# Java8: Filter and map on same method output

Tags: java-8, java-stream

We are trying to refactor below code to java 8:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<Obj> i = x.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   String y = m(i.next().getKey());
   if (y != null) {
      list.add(y);
   }
}
return list;
```

So far we have come up with:

```
return x.stream()
  .filter(s -> m(s.getKey()) != null)
  .map(t -> m(t.getKey()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But the method `m()` is being invoked twice here. Is there any way around?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well you can do the filtering after the mapping step:

```
x.stream()
  .map(s -> m(s.getKey()))
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```